# How to install Pentaho DI CE 5 on centos

Tags: centos, pentaho, etl, business-intelligence

I am trying to install Pentaho communitty edition on `centos 6`

From here

http://sourceforge.net/projects/pentaho/files/Data%20Integration/5.0.1-stable/pdi-ce-5.0.1.A-stable.zip/download

Now in the installtion mnaual they say this

http://infocenter.pentaho.com/help/index.jsp?topic=%2Finstall_pdi%2Fconcept_archive_pdi_instal.html

```
Linux:

./install.sh
```

But there is no install.sh file in data-integration folder

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you downloaded pentaho di and unzipped it, that's enough..

just set java_home and execute ./kitchen.sh or ./pan.sh

the link you mansion they people are not saying to execute ./install.sh..

Comment: thanks for that and i will do that but they do mention to run install.sh here http://postimg.org/image/qgo2vlb9l/

Comment: never worked with enterprise edition, just give a try if it is working or not.